# How it is possible that I have many more users (Suscribers) in my blog that visits?

Tags: wordpress

I have created a blog a few weeks ago and have started to add posts about SQL-Server ([Tips For DBs](http://tips4dbs.com/)).

Very quickly I started to receive new suscribers (New User Registration) and now I have already 175.
But... it is very strange because I also have activated at the beginning the Google Analytics and I see just 1 or 2 visits per day, reflecting a total of 13 different users that have accessed the blog.
Anyone has an idea of what is happening? 
How is possible that there are so many people suscribing the Blog that have never accessed it?

The blog has been created as an standard WordPress in a hosted domain. Just installed WordPress and activated some Plug-Ins: AddToAny Share Buttons, Akismet Anti-Spam, Goolytics - Simple Google Analytics, SpiceBox (Template) and Gutenberg. 
For Goolitics, I just set the code that Google Analytics shows. That's all, no code, just that plug-ins and a few posts.

Comment: There must be an error in either your subscriber count or the implementation of the GA tag. But you’d need to provide code for us to help trouble shoot

Comment: bots can subsribe into your website. also, check comments. mainly, bots trying to add spam comments, or crash website by trying thouthands admin login datas for detecting right one

Comment: Has sense that are bots as if would be someone entering in the Blog, should be reflected as a new visitor in Google Analytics what is not the case. Maybe are bots trying to introduce SPAM but they cannot because the Akismet Anti-Smap plug-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Akismet will help you in reducing the SPAM comments and not the users creation. As per Akismet "Akismet is a spam fighting service that protects millions of WordPress sites from comment and contact form spam."

Adding and configuring following plugins will help you reduce the number of SPAM registrations

- Email Verification on Signup https://wordpress.org/plugins/email-verification-on-signups/
- User Verification https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-verification/
- Google ReCaptcha https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-captcha/
- WP Approve Users https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-approve-user/

From the plugins list it seems there are no Web Application Firewall - Security plugins in place, It is highly recommended to use the security plugins on WordPress.

Comment: Wonderful answer, just after activating the filters I have no new suscribers (robots) trying to introduce SPAM in my blog. Many thanks !!!